# Detecting when iOS Webclip is launched whilst working around an iOS 13 bug

Tags: javascript, ios, dom, mobile-safari, ios13

### Background

I install full screen web apps to the home screen of an iOS device and run some `javascript` each time the web app is launched.
Apple have made a change in iOS 13 whereby scripts are only run the first time it is launched. Each subsequent launch presents the web app from where it left off without refreshing back to the start (unless it has been removed from the app switcher).

> I believe this is a much requested feature from Web App developers to stop a webpage refreshing if the user switches to another app and back again

To make `javascript` run some code each time the app is brought to the foreground or launched, I thought I could simply use some notifications watching `focus`, `blur` & `visibilitychange` or maybe looking at `document.activeElement`, `document.hasFocus()` or `document.hidden`.

Here's the gotcha...

iOS 13 has also introduced a bug that I have reported but doesn't look like it's going to be fixed any time soon and is still present in 13GM & 13.1 beta.

### Bug

If you have more than one home screen web app, it's as if they all share the same web container. Launching a 2nd web app causes all the focus type notifications to fire on previously opened web apps as if they had become front and centre again. This means any `javascript` code is going to run as if it had been launched, even when it hasn't.

### Question

I am trying to find a way around this bug and be notified when a web app is launched front and centre. Using `onLoad` type code will only run once whilst the web app is left in the app switcher. Watching `focus` type events will fire unnecessarily as other web apps are launched. Are there any other events or methods I can try calling, or any tricks I could try to implement?

## EDIT

As requested, here is example html:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>visibilitychange</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black-translucent">
</head>
<body id="body">
    <h1>visibilitychange</h1>
    <h3>Save this web clip to your home screen, then when you open it it'll automatically list the times the visibilitychange notification is called and the state</h3>
    <br /><br />

    <p>Initial page visibility was <b id="status">unknown</b>.</p>
    <div id="target"></div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = document.hidden ? 'hidden' : 'visible';

        var target = document.getElementById('target');
        function logToScreen(text) {
            var timeBadge = new Date().toTimeString().split(' ')[0];
            var newState = document.createElement('p');
            newState.innerHTML = '<span class="badge">' + timeBadge + '</span> ' + text + '</b>';
            target.appendChild(newState);
        }

        function isPageHidden() {
            console.log('isPageHidden() ==' + document.visibilityState);
            logToScreen('isPageHidden() ==' + document.visibilityState);
            return document.visibilityState == 'hidden'; // document.hidden;
        }

        document.addEventListener("visibilitychange", function(event) 
        {
            console.log('visibilitychange event listener');
            logToScreen('visibilitychange event listener');
            if(!isPageHidden()) {
                console.log('page opened');
                logToScreen('page opened');
            }
        }, false);
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you try or tried:

```
 function  isPageHidden(){
 return document.hidden; //document.visibilityState == 'hidden'
  }

window.addEventListener("focus", function(event) 
 { 
   If(!isPageHidden())
   // do something
   }, false);
```

or

```
document.addEventListener('visibilitychange', function(){
     If(!isPageHidden())
       // do something
       }, false);
});
```

Another way is workaround: save last timestamp of performed  action in localstorage and check in related event (focus, blur, visibility) if  interval has reached for perform javascript run task.

Updates:

```
window.addEventListener('locationchange', function(){
    console.log('location changed!');
   //check current location.pathname
})
```

or

```
  window.onhashchange = function() { 
         console.log('location changed!');
       //check current location.pathname 
    }
```

Comment: I've just tested this and it acts really weird. Firstly it doesn't fire the first time the web app is opened, but does every time after that, however once I opened a different web app and come back to this one, it doesn't fire at all.

Comment: what about visibilitychange event? i edited the answer

Comment: Same. It seems `document.hidden` also returns `false` when another web app is opened :(

Comment: and document.visibilityState == 'hidden'?

Comment: Same :( I think the bug in iOS 13 is treating all web apps as using the same container and sharing the same variables across them all maybe.

Comment: can you please  post the version of code that you use in last one.

Comment: I've added it above as an edit to the question. If you have an iOS 13 device you can test it also by going to `https://venderbase.com/vischange3.html` and `https://venderbase.com/nojs.html` add both to your home screen. Open vischange, go back to home screen, open nojs and go back to home screen a few times, open vischange again and you'll see it shows that it had opened many times when it didn't.

Comment: Last one: what about approach only  for  event like 'trigger' and interval checking for updates as workaround?

Comment: My use case can occur over long periods of time. I use js to launch apps through URL schemes, so a user launching a new app later on will cause the previous launched app from earlier to launch.

Comment: i cannot check now but edited answer with another way of location changed event. may be bug will try to trigger the event

Comment: Great idea, but unfortunately no good. The location never changes. I even tested logging the `location.pathname` when the `visibilitychange` notification gets fired by the 2nd web app, and it shows the original pathname.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199839/discussion-between-oleg-and-darren).

Comment: try validate if document.title is changed in visibilitychange event and also with Event.stopPropagation() ,Event.stopPropagation()  and Event.preventDefault(), please track orders of events

Comment: Although we never found a solution, I have awarded you the bounty payment for spending so much time trying to help. Thanks

Comment: Hi, thank you, but what  about idea:  listen to visibilitychange event  as a trigger and check interval 
from last one for make some app related updates, you can also store last update timestamp in storage for each app.

Comment: You can manage key for each app and timestamp  for the decision.